# How to replace many to many reference on join in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I create a simple data base on 3 tables: Author, that can has many Books, and Genre that also can has many Books.

[image]

I want to get all Genres of one Author using it `authorId`. I wrote next nested SQL select:

```
SELECT genre.id, genre.genre_id, genre.genre_name, genre.genre_descr FROM (SELECT book.genre_id FROM book WHERE book.author_id = 7654) AS b JOIN genre WHERE b.genre_id = genre.genre_id;
```

It works good for me, but is it possible some minimize this select? For example, get rid of nested select?

Yes, I know, that the good solution is to create reference many to many beetwen genre and author, but it will add some complications...

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there. A simple join will do

`SELECT DISTINCT g.* FROM genre g JOIN book b ON g.id = b.genre_id AND b.author_id = 7654`

If you slow reads, then index on `author_id` should just work.

Comment: It works, but I need to return exectly genres objects, without joined values from book table to parse it in JpaRepository to Genre model.

Comment: I have updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution without using `join`:

```
select * from genre where id in (select genre_id from book where author_id = 7654)
```